# django-registration. Try Django 1.8 Tutorial. OperationalError at /accounts/register/

Tags: python, django, django-registration

Yesterday I followed a tutorial django course from CodingEntrepreneurs. When I finished my application, I tried to use the registration, but it gives me the following error:

```
OperationalError at /accounts/register/
table registration_registrationprofile has no column named activated
```

I tried to runserver the github repository of this course (link-https://github.com/codingforentrepreneurs/Try-Django-1.8) and I got the same result.

Makemigrations/migrate- tried. Gives me :

```
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self,query)django.db.utils.OperationalError: 
table "registration_registrationprofile" already exists
```

Here is the decription of the problem:

```
Django Version: 1.9.1
Python Version: 2.7.10
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'registration',
 'newsletter')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

(skip)

File "/home/popovvasile/Desktop/programming/trydjanggo/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py" in execute
  323.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /accounts/register/
Exception Value: table registration_registrationprofile has no column named activated
```

Here is an example of an deployed site - https://nix1947.herokuapp.com/.
 Using the registration (not the sing-up form) gives an error.

link for the course- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsLHt3D_jsE&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzRcd-q4vR5qAgOZUuz8041S

Did anyone follow the same tutorial course ? Thank you.

Comment: do you have saved information in your database? if not, try to remove your database and also migration files then migrate again with `migrate - makemigration - sqlmigrate <app_name> 0001`

Comment: Your migrations seems to be messed up somehow. This can be challenging to fix. It's probably easer to clean out the database and start from skratch as @ArashHatami suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using django-registration package instead django-registration-redux

1. Remove django-registration
2. Install django-registration-redux
3. Migrate

it's helped me

Django 2.0.2, python 3.6.4

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem 
I've chnage requirement.txt to:

```
Django==1.8.17
django-crispy-forms==1.6.1
django-registration-redux==1.1
```

and run in command line

> pip3 install -r requirements.txt